# jquery animate only opacity left to right

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, opacity

Is it possible to animate only the opacity, and have it move in a direction across a div? Let's say from left to right?

Here is my code so far: just missing something that says Left, if it's even feasible:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#box').mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).animate({opacity: ".5"}, 500);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the CSS `linear-gradient` property and then run an animation loop to vary where it changes.  Here is a quick [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K3yGM/2/) showing the effect.

The basic idea is to set the CSS based on the animation progress.  For example, using a white background fading to transparent, at 25% complete you'd have:

```
background: linear-gradient(to right,
  rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%,
  rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25) 25%,
  rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100);
```

And on subsequent steps change the `0.25` and `25%` to the current progress percent.  The Javascript from the fiddle looks like:

```
var $child = $('#child');
var steps = 100;
var interval = 20;
var step = 0;
var animationStep = function() {
    if( step >= steps ) return;
    ++step;
    var progress = step / steps;
    var progressPercent = Math.floor(progress*100) + '%';
    $child.css('background',
        'linear-gradient(to right, ' +
            'rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, ' +
            'rgba(255,255,255,' + progress + ') ' + progressPercent + ', ' +
            'rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%)'
    );
    setTimeout(animationStep, interval);
};
animationStep();
```

You could adapt this to be more general use in terms of colors, reusing on multiple elements, etc, but this should give you the basic idea.

Comment: Thank you Jake! Much more complex than I would have imagined, but it works.

Comment: You're welcome.  I just updated the answer with a slightly nicer version that will finish completely opaque.  The original still had some transparency when it completed.

Comment: **+1** Nice way to fake opacity

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>Animation</title>

    <script src="js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="mydiv" style="height:20px; width:49px; opacity:0.5; background-color:green;">
    </div>

    <script>
        $('#mydiv').hover(
            function(){
                $(this).animate({height:40,width:200,opacity:1});
            },
            function(){
                $(this).animate({height:20,width:100,opacity:0.5});
            }
        );
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. However that just expands the box, I'm looking for just the opacity to change across the div from left to right.